# Unable to write data to Firebase Realtime Database | Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for the first time so I followed their guide step by step. I am trying to write to the database using their sample code, yet that doesn't seem to work.

This is the code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message");
mDatabase.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

This is the database from the Firebase console:

```
project-name-1cade: null
```

These are the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This is what the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio shows me:

1. Connect your app to firebase -> Connected
2. Add the Realtime Database to your app -> Dependencies setup correctly

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you link project to same firebase project, you are viewing on firebase console?

Comment: yes, I do authentication too and that works with Firebase

Comment: try .getReference("message").child("test").value("abc")